# Create a loop that will output all the multiples of 5 that are greater than zero and less than 60 (do not include 60)

Tags: c++, loops, dev-c++

This is an assignment I have due Monday and the teacher won't email me back. My code works but it keeps showing 0 as a result and I don't know why and every time I try to fix it, the entire thing breaks. The instructions are: Create a loop that will output all the multiples of 5 that are greater than zero and
less than 60 (do not include 60). This is the code that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
 int multiples, count;
 multiples = 5;
 count = 0;

while (count < 60){
    printf("%i \n", count);
    count = multiples + count;
    if (count)
}
system("pause");
```

I genuinely don't get what I'm doing wrong here. I get that I can't just do (count < 60 && count > 0) because I've made the count = 0 but I need to get rid of the resulting 0 preferably without rewriting my entire code.

Comment: Why would it not print `0`? In situations like this it is helpful to rubber duck it and explain to yourself why your code is correct.

Comment: Does this have to be a `while` loop? It absolutely can be done with `while`, but `for` might be a more natural loop choice.

Comment: @GBlodgett if the code is `count = multiples + count` then wouldn't the first thing it runs be `count = 5 + 0` which equals 5 so why would it be 0 first?

Comment: The first thing it runs is `printf`. That happens before the `count = multiples + count`, while count is still 0.

Comment: @erichamion How did I miss that? Thank you for pointing that out it runs the way I need it to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't start with 0, and it's better, to exactly multiply

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int multiplier, count, value;
multiplier = 5;
count = 1;

do {
    value = count * multiplier;
    count++;
    printf("%i \n", value);
} while (value < 60)
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

`0` is being printed because the first time `printf("%i \n", count);` is reached in the while loop, count is still 0. In order to fix that, you just need to switch the lines (have `count = multiples + count;` before `printf("%i \n", count);`).

Also, in order to avoid priniting 60, you'll need to add a if condition.

```
while (count < 60){
    count = multiples + count;
    if(count!=60) {
        printf("%i \n", count);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, You can also just start `count` from 5:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int multiples, count;
multiples = 5;
count = 5;

while (count < 60){
    printf("%i \n", count);
    count = multiples + count;
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: I believe the while condition needs to be changed here. This will print 60 at the end.

Comment: @erichamion You are right, I was referring to the issue about printing 0

Comment: @EyalGolan I could start `count` at 5 but I've been working on this assignment for hours and I'm going change as little as possible in hopes that it doesn't mess up the rest of my code and I can take a break

Comment: @AnnieL If you are using a decent source control system (like git), which you *should*, you can always just commit your changes and take a break, then later make more changes, and if they break stuff you just go back to your previous commit. Commit often.. and please don't say you are not using source/version control..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the `for` loop to count the multiples of 5 under 60 in one single code line:

```
int count=0;
for (int i=5; i<60; i+=5) {cout<<i<<'\n'; count++;}
cout<<"Total multiples: "<<count;
```

Another way to make it is using a `do-while` loop in order to change the count value before it gets evaluated by the `while` clause.